# Integrating trigonometric quotients

Tags: integration

This is my final question:

8. Consider the function $ g(x) = \frac{\sin^3 x}{
   1 + \cos x}$.
   Write $g(x) = f(u, v)$, where $u = \sin x$ and $v = \cos x$.
   Consulting Section 18.16 on p.299 of Ostaszewski’s book if necessary, evaluate $\int_0^{π/2}\frac{\sin^3 x}{
   1 + \cos x}dx$

---

I got the answer using this method: 
$\sin^3x=\sin^2x\times \sin x=(1-\cos^2x)\times\sin x=(1+\cos x)(1-\cos x)\times \sin x$

And then cancelling out the $1+\cos x$ term. Is this the best way to tackle this question or was I being expected to use some other method? I don't have the book that the question references so I wasn't sure. I feel like I was supposed to do something with the fact that $g(x)=\frac{u^3}{1+v}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I bought the book ... £62 :'( lol

Basically the book states a set of substitutions to use according to the nature of the function $f(\sin x, \cos x)$

In this case it states that if we consider that $f(\sin x, \cos x) = \frac{\sin^3 x}{1+\cos x}$ is an odd function with respect to $\sin$, i.e. $f(\sin x, \cos x) = -f(-\sin x,\cos x)$ then $w=\ cos x$ is a suitable substitution.

$w = \cos x \rightarrow \frac{dw}{dx}=-\sin x \rightarrow dx = \frac{-dw}{\sin x}$

$\int_{x=0}^{\pi / 2} \frac{\sin^3x}{1+\cos x}dx$

$=\int_{w=1}^{0} \frac{\sin^3x}{1+ w}\times \frac{-1}{sin x}dw$

$=\int_1^0 \frac{-\sin^2x}{1+w}dw$

$=-\int_1^0 \frac{1-\cos^2x}{1+w}dw$

$=-\int_1^0 \frac{1 - w^2}{1+w}dw$

$=-\int_1^0 \frac{(1+w)(1-w)}{1+w}dw$

$=-\int_1^0 (1-w)dw$

$=-[w-\frac{w^2}{2}]_1^0$

$=-[(0-\frac{0^2}{2})-(1-\frac{1^2}{2})]$

$=-[(0)-(1-\frac{1}{2})]$

$=-[(0)-(\frac{1}{2})]$

$=-[-\frac{1}{2}]$

$=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{\sin^3(x)}{1+\cos(x)}dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{\sin(x)(1-\cos^2(x))}{1+\cos(x)}dx$

Substitute $u=\cos(x)$

$I =-\int_1^0\dfrac{1-u^2}{1+u}du=\int_0^1(1-u)du=\dfrac{1}2$

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is sort of close to what I did. I was curious to know if there was a way to answer the question using the function $f(u,v)$ that the question got me to produce before going on to evaluate the integral.

Comment: This method seems the easiest and the most natural to me. @JamesStott Tbh, I'm not too sure how to do it with the function $g$.